# Remove Class name and Again add it using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i wanted to remove class name and replace it with another class name using jquery or js.

```
        <th id="SUN" scope="col" class="t-ClassicCalendar-dayColumn">
        <span class="visible-md visible-lg">Sunday   </span>
        <span class="hidden-md hidden-lg">Sun</span>
        </th>
```

As shown in above code where class name is "visible-md visible-lg" there i wanted "hidden-md hidden-lg" and where class name is "hidden-md hidden-lg" there i wanted "visible-md visible-lg" so output will be : Sun and not Sunday.
This should happened on page Load not on Click.
thank you

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: yes i have tried addClass class and removeClass but it should work at the same time.If i remove class first then eventually both span will have same class and vise versa

Comment: i think not everybody should give a fiddle i think the question is clear and is not answered in the duplicate marked question...

Comment: Thank you Cyril i dont know why Arun P Johny marked this as Duplicate with Wrong Link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) method of jquery.

Example for your case

```
$("span").removeClass("visible-md visible-lg");
```

then use `addClass`

```
$("span").addClass("hidden-md hidden-lg");
```

You can do some toggle based on logic like

```
if (add) {
  $(span).addClass(className);
} else {
  $(span).removeClass(className);
}
```

Comment: need to use if else condition else both span will have same class
i wanted to unhide second span also

Comment: you can use toggleclass or I have added .

Comment: Tried in DOM gives me error : 
VM11733:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list(…)InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM11641:875InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM11641:808InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM11641:664

Comment: i would suggest you to create a fiddle or plnkr in that case.

Comment: i am not expert in JS or jquery i am a oracle guy so don't know how fiddle works :)

Comment: as error clearly states you have some syntax error .check minutely what is that.

Comment: You can use toggle class
check it http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZxeOO

Comment: @arun i have created simple demo over here which where i am confused how actually this add remove works  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVrRxJ

i need to pass id also else every span will get affected

Comment: I checked it, you have not defined click event. I just updated it. Toggle actually switches between classes.
For more info refer yo http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Actually i wanted on page load not on click that is why i removed click event

Comment: Is it possible we can pass ID as a value
something like 
<span class="hidden-md hidden-lg">ID(SUN)</span>